# Jmeter - Duration Based Run's abort prematurely without executing all the transactions

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario related to ecommerce, threadgroup has 10 transaction controllers & each controller has multiple samplers,

i am running test in an duration based run's, when the test duration is over, test is getting stoped prematurely without executing all the transactions, jmeter is not considering to executing the remining transactions which are need to be executed.

Is there a way to instruct JMeter to wait until each thread has finished its flow, user job, or transaction controller before killing it?

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) it's not possible, you have the following options:

1. Instead of setting the duration set the fixed number of iterations in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Decide if to stop the thread by using [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and [Flow Control Action Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) combination. Like:

   ```
   if delta between current time and the start time of the test is larger than X seconds -> stop the thread.
   ```